# Replacing rows in a matrix in a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to write a simple Markov model in R. To generate the Markov trace I created a empty matrix with ncol=number of states, and nrow=number of cycles. I am writing a function using a loop to replace each row of the matrix with each cycle, but the loop is failing me.

```
Rounds<-function(cycles,TransMatrix){
  for (i in 1:nrow(MarkovTrace)){
    MarkovTrace[i+1,]<-as.vector(MarkovTrace[i,]%*%TransMatrix)
  }
}
```

Any thoughts on why this is? 
I am able to do this manually outside of the loop, though.

```
MarkovTrace[2,]<-as.vector(MarkovTrace[1,]%*%TransMatrix)
MarkovTrace[3,]<-as.vector(MarkovTrace[2,]%*%TransMatrix)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: When you say that it's failing, what is it telling you? Does it say that the array index is out of bounds? If so, loop until `nrow(MarkovTrace)-1`. (Note the -1.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<<-` operator to affect a variable from outer scopes. However also consider a coding style that obviates this need as it will make your code  more re-usable and easier to debug.

Comment: A short comment on functional programming that you might like: http://www.opensourceforu.com/2012/05/functional-programming-and-python/

Comment: Alternatively, pass `MarkovTrace` as a third argument to the function and return `MarkovTrace` after the `for` loop.